# Mute/unmute button using icon - jQuery

Tags: jquery, audio

So basically I want to have a button to mute my audio, so i've set my audio to auto-start upon load, now I want it so the user is able to mute the audio.

I've set my link inside div and styled my link so that it's just a mute icon with the id of #mute, the audio has an id of #audio.

What kind of jQuery would I need in order to pause or stop the audio? Here's what I've come up with so far...

```
$(function(){
$("#mute").click(function(){
    $("#audio").stop();
});
});
```

Comment: what typ of audio plugin are you using?

Comment: @Zorken17 what do you mean?  `<audio controls class="sr-only" autoplay="true" loop="true" id="audio">
  <source src="/images/horrormusic.ogg" type="audio/ogg" id="audio">
</audio>`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('input').click(function() {
 if($('audio').attr('muted') == undefined){
    $('audio').attr('muted', '');
      $('input').val('Unmute')
    } else {
    $('audio').removeAttr('muted');
      $('input').val('Mute')
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<audio controls>
</audio>

<br/>
<input type="button" value="Mute" />
```

Comment: What dose not work, my button is muting and unmuting the audio player? I think you need to give us your al html code

Comment: It's okay, I fixed it by using:  `$(document).ready(function(){  
$("#audio").prop('muted', false);

  $("#mute").click( function (){
    if( $("#audio").prop('muted') ) {
          $("#audio").prop('muted', false);
    } else {
      $("#audio").prop('muted', true);
    }`  p.s: Why won't my line break in the Stack Overflow comment box? I'm adding two spaces at the end of the line?